# Balancing out 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I need to sort a 2d array. Unfortunately `std::sort()` isn't an option.

I have an int `array[3][4]` and I have to insert values from an `int array[12]` into it.
I'm supposed to "balance" the columns so that the values of each column is almost equal or at least as close to it as it gets.

In the end it's supposed to look a little something like this:

```
Tier 4:   8|11|12
Tier 3:   5|10|9
Tier 2:   4|6|7
Tier 1:   3|2|1
```

Comment: What have you tried? Will this always be a continuous sequence of numbers or abitrary ones?

Comment: "Sort a 2d array". Makes no sense. You can sort a sequence.

Comment: Given two arrangements, how do you determine that one is better balanced than the other?

Answer (score 1):

sort the initial array; you do have the initial array array[12]. Then insert them into the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the 1D array (arr1[12]) and then insert the elements in 2d array (arr2[3][4]) in a way something like... fill 1st row from left to right, then 2nd row from right to left, then 3rd row left to right...and so on.

the logic would be like :

```
// Let's say the int arr1[12] is the sorted one
int flag = 0, c = 0;
for(int i =0; i < 4; ++1) {
    if( (1+1)%2 == 0) {
        c = 2;
        flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        flag = 0;
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        if(flag) {
            arr2[i][c] = arr1[n++];
            --c;
        }
        else {
            arr2[i][k] = arr1[n++];
        }
    }
}
```